# How do I set font for text but keep font in equations in Word with VBA?

Tags: vba, fonts, ms-word

I want to set the font of all texts to Times New Roman, and I wrote these codes:

```
Selection.WholeStory
With Selection.Font
    .NameAscii = "Times New Roman"
    .NameOther = "Times New Roman"
    .Name = ""
End With
```

However, when I run those codes, the font of all equations, i.e. Omath objects becomes Times New Roman too, instead of Cambria Math.

I've tried to add these codes after that:

```
For Each Oma In NewDoc.OMaths
    With Oma.Range.Font
        .Italic = True
        .Name = "Cambria Math"
    End With
    DoEvents
Next
```

This **does** work, but it's **too slow** since there's a for-loop in the code.

However, when I just press Ctrl+A to select the whole story and set the font manually, Word will skip the equations automatically while in VBA it doesn't.

Therefore I wonder is there a good way to set the font of texts but keep the font of equations? Very much thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to find and replace as @Timothy Rylatt suggested. Here's my code:

```
Sub FindReplaceFont()
   With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = ""
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = True
      .Font.Name = "Consolas"
      .Replacement.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
End Sub
```

But I met a strange problem: after find and replace, texts between two inline equations will merge in one equation object. Here're the pics:

Before replacing the document looks like this:
[image: The original document]

And after replacing the document looks like this:
[image: The modified document]

I've met this problem before and I still have no idea why this could happen and how to deal with it. Any suggestions for me?

Thank you guys again.

**UPDATE:**

I've solved this problem following the suggestion from @macropod. I should set the font of the styles instead of setting them directly. A simple for-loop on the styles is OK!

Comment: Brute-force font changes are an appallingly poor way of managing document formatting. This should all be done by updating the relevant Style definitions. That way, too, you'd have no Omath issue to resolve.

Comment: @macropod Yeah, of course, you're absolutely right, but the documents I'm dealing with are results from OCR, the formats of which are disordered. Therefore I'd wonder solution to format the documents in a specific font.

Comment: Regardless, such documents must at least employ the Normal Style; it's unavoidable. And it doesn't take all that much effort to work out what other Styles are in use.

Comment: @macropod OMG, yes, you're right! I'm essentially wrong on this problem! I should change the font of the Styles instead of setting fonts directly. The problem has been perfectly solved! If you'd like to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: If you change the font of 'Normal' style you also need to set the default font for the document. The simplest way of doing this is from the Font dialog - select the font you want then click Set As Default. However, you also need to set the Document Defaults which is done from the Manage Styles dialog (find it at the bottom of the styles pane) and ensure that the Normal style exactly matches the defaults. This can only be done through the UI.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt Thanks for your suggestions. What I need is to set default fonts for many documents, neither some nor all of my documents. Therefore I suppose a VBA script to set the relevant Styles is a perfect idea, isn't it?

Comment: Whilst you can use VBA to set the font of the 'Normal' style, which will then cascade down to all the styles that are based on it, you can't set the document default via VBA. For table styles to work correctly the 'Normal' style must match the document defaults and the table has to be inserted in a paragraph formatted in that style. This is explained in a [Microsoft blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20110221075603/http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2008/10/28/behind-the-curtain-styles-doc-defaults-style-sets-and-themes.aspx) from 2008.

Comment: For existing documents the simplest solution is to use theme fonts and change the theme to one that uses the font you require. Theme fonts have been the default since Office 2007. This can be done via VBA `ActiveDocument.ApplyDocumentTheme "Full path to document theme file"`. For new documents you should be using templates that are set up with the correct formatting.

Comment: @Timothy Rylatt I got it! Very much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is as simple as:

```
ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
```

Answer (score 2):

It rather depends on how you formatted the document to begin with.

If you've applied the font manually rather than use styles your best option is to use Find and Replace.

```
Sub FindReplaceFont()
   With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .text = ""
      .Replacement.text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = True
      .Font.name = "Existing Font Name"
      .Replacement.Font.name = "Times New Roman"
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
End Sub
```

If you've used styles, or you've just left everything in the default 'Normal' style, you can change the font of the base style, which is 'Normal'.

```
ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
```

NOTE: It is not possible to change the default font correctly using VBA unless you are using Theme Fonts. For Table Styles to work correctly the font for Normal must match the document default, which can only be set via the UI.

Comment: Very much thanks! I've tried the find-and-replace solution. It works well. However, I met a strange problem which I've illustrated in the update of my post. Could you please give me any suggestions on this problem?